# AdMob ad test banner NEVER load in mediation

Tags: ios, admob, ios-simulator, iad

```
 -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

self.iAdbanner.hidden=YES;

 _bannerView=[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

 self.bannerView.adUnitID=@"UNIT_ID";

 self.bannerView.rootViewController=self;

 [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];  

self.bannerView.delegate = self;  

_bannerView.hidden=NO;

 GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];

 request.testDevices= @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];  

 [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];

 }
```

Only the iAd test banner loads. However, when the iAd test banner fails, I don't understand why AdMob test banner never loads in simulator and device. Didn't I implement the correct code for AdMob test banner to fill the spot of iAd banner failures?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off creating a Singleton class Ad banner to share a single ad on multiple view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the size you are requesting? Something like:

```
self.bannerView.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait;
```